# DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException + PDOException: Can't update!

Tags: 7, upgrading

I´ve read many posts about this problem, and tried many things, before deciding to open this one. This is the issue:

**1.** I upgrade my D6 site and all it´s contrib modules to latest D6 versions.

**2.** I disable all contrib modules.

**3.** I try to upgrade to D7, the same way I usually upgrade (deleting old core files and adding the new ones).

**4.** After upgrading everything, and run the update.php script, I encounter that all my admin pages show a message “You do not have any administrative items”. I´ve read several posts about this error, and decide to run the update script again, because it probably didn´t finished.

**5.** That was true, I´ve had 14 updates pending. So after running the script again, this error appears:

> Update #7061: Failed: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Table system_update_7061 already exists. in
>   DatabaseSchema->createTable() (line 657 of
>   /home/public_html/includes/database/schema.inc). So after reading that
>   this is some sort of a Drupal unresolved bug, I delete that table
>   (system_update_7061), so it can create it again.

**6.** I run the update script again and found a new error:

> System Update #7061: Failed: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'public://proyecto.zip' for
>   key 2: INSERT INTO {file_managed} (fid, uid, filename, uri, filemime,
>   filesize, status, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1889
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   proyecto.zip [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => public://proyecto.zip
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => application/zip
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 22989 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 0 ) in system_update_7061() (line 2816
>   of/home/public_html/modules/system/system.install).

So, I´ve read in a post that this error could happen because of a problem with files that have caps letters, and that they can be considered duplicate, etc.
So, after trying a lot (I´ve changed the filename, the uri, the fid and the uid associated to that file), I decided to delete that entry.

**7.** I run again the update script (after deleting the system_update_7061 table, because it was recreated when I tried to upgrade the second time), and found the the same error appeared again. So, the entry was there again! It was re created but I´m in square one again, because the error persists, and each time I try to delete the entry, it is recreated by the script, before it can finish.
I must add that, yes, the /admin pages do still tell me the nasty message “You do not have any administrative items”.

**8.** Please note that I´ve followed the instructions here ([Drupal 7 and the "You do not have any administrative items" error](http://languor.us/drupal-7-and-you-do-not-have-any-administrative-items-error)), and while I can access the menu links from admin/structure/menu/manage/management, I still get the error message under admin/ link. I´ve cleared the cache and nothing happened.
And I´ve checked the admin/modules link and ALL contributed modules are "incompatible" with Drupal 7, when I upgraded them!!

What can I do??
Please help, any insight will be very much apperciated!!